# Wordpress Theme Upload Nginx 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wordpress, docker

Hi I am setting up a new website to be based on containerized WordPress with Nginx, MariaDb 10.8 Wordpress 6.2 containers. I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy at the front end. Everything seems to be working until I try to upload my new theme .zip file when I get an error from nginx saying 413 Request Entity Too Large. I have tried setting the client_max_body_size 0 in nginx.conf which doesn't seem to work. I have rebuilt the image which also doesn't work. I have worked with wordpress before but I am new to Linux and docker so please bear with me.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        # server_name your_domain www.your_domain;
        server_name localhost

        client_max_body_size 0;

        client_body_buffer_size 16K;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        root /var/www/html;

        autoindex on;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
        
        location = /favicon.ico { 
                log_not_found off; access_log off; 
        }
        location = /robots.txt { 
                log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; 
        }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.8
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=hotspotdb
    volumes: 
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on: 
      - db
    image: wordpress:6.2.0-fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MARIADB_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MARIADB_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=hotspotdb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network

  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin:5.2.1
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      MARIADB_USER: stephen # Remove line for production
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: $MARIADB_PASSWORD # Remove line for production
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  wordpress:
  dbdata:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```